# I want to store a bunch of data in an array, for use in various different classes. How?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, nsmutablearray, nsarray

So i've tried and tried at this and for the most part it's worked, but with it's problems. I need to start again though with this. So can somebody explain the best way that I can have an array in my app which allows other classes to access it, edit it, delete items from it and add new items?

Answer (score 1):

You can probably have it declared as an instance variable in `appDelegate` so it can be easily accessed by other classes

```
YourAppDelegate *appDelegate = (YourAppDelegate *)[[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate];
//and then access the variable by appDelegate.variable
```

Answer (score 0):

If u declare array in the appDelegate you can access the array in all other classes using main appDelegate instance.